# why is PostForm not redirecting in golang gae?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am trying to post a form using golang. My code is below

```
client := urlfetch.Client(c)

resp, err := client.PostForm("example.com", url.Values{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

I am getting 200 OK response but it is not redirecting to example.com

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @3of3 yeah, take it to the page where example.com takes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [net.http.Client.PostForm()](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm)  issues a POST to the specified URL, with data's keys and values urlencoded as the request body.

But that doesn't mean it instruct the target website to redirect anything.
As [shown in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/9LccRMzXK74), the client would follow a redirect only if the website returned a [302 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), respecting the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) web development design pattern that prevents some duplicate form submissions.
([Issue 4145](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4145), fixed with [commit 08ce7f1](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/08ce7f1d5c309cf4187fbb1e442ee4388c29212b) for go 1.1, May 2013)

Comment: so suppose i am taking values from client and in my program i am sending a post request to my payment gateway. now the client should be on payment gateway page after the post request. How should i handle that?

Comment: @vvincirey that would be to the server to handle: if it sends back a redirect directive, then the client will end up on the redirected page. If not, it will stay on the payment gateway page.